# SQL Server - How to use a Column value which has already been unpivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to use a Column values that has already been unpivot into a new table.
For example, we have a table that have a list of Column Names: `[ID]`, `[Name]`, `[Country]`, `[PostCode]`, `[Address]`.
The Code I have (Note: Convert is for union purpose to have unique type)

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  FieldName,
  FieldValue
FROM (SELECT
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [ID]) AS [ID],
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [Name]) AS [Name],
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [Country]) AS [Country],
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [PostCode]) AS [PostCode],
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [Address]) AS [Address]
     FROM table) pv
UNPIVOT
(FieldValue FOR FieldName IN ([ID], [Name], [Country] 
[PostCode], [Address])) unp
```

But the above code will cause an issue that

> Invalid column name 'ID'.

Is there any way to include the ID as a column name and all ID value as the list of values in the [ID] column?

For example,
we have an original table

```
ID    Name    Country    PostCode    Address
1     Jack    Australia  1234        Wyard
2     John    China      3223        Belconnen
3     Ed      UK         1123        Rose
```

I want to have the table will be look like below

```
ID   FieldName   FieldValue 
1    ID          1
1    Name        Jack
1    Country     Australia
1    PostCode    1234
1    Address     Wyard
2    ID          2
2    Name        Leo
...    ...       ...
```

Comment: I recommend that you give some example input data and the result you'd like from that example data.  At present it's not clear what you are trying achieve.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create another column using ID with some other alias in the nested query and don't refer it in the list of unpivoting columns.

```
SELECT 
  ID_C AS [ID],
  FieldName,
  FieldValue
FROM (SELECT
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [ID]) AS [ID_C],
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [ID]) AS [ID],
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [Name]) AS [Name],
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [Country]) AS [Country],
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [PostCode]) AS [PostCode],
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [Address]) AS [Address]
     FROM table) pv
UNPIVOT
(FieldValue FOR FieldName IN ([ID], [Name], [Country] 
[PostCode], [Address])) unp
```

This will require very less changes in your current query

Comment: This is a awesome solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `apply` for this purpose:

```
SELECT t.ID, v.FieldName, v.FieldValue
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [ID]), 'ID'),
             (CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [Name]), 'Name'),
             (CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [Country]), 'Country'),
             (CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [PostCode]), 'PostCode'),
             (CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), [Address]), 'Address')
     ) v(FieldValue, FieldName);
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but this way can not get the ID as the FieldType and ID values as the FieldValue.

Comment: @user3651247 . . . Just add it to the `VALUES` list.  I thought you wanted it as an `id` on each row.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Yes, actually I want [ID] to be appeared in each row and as well as in the FieldType and FieldValue columns. This is fixed. Thanks a lot for your kindly advice.